# Joining shape to external data using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm developing an application that uses Shapes only to draw the map. 
I would like to "Inject" the data at the time of viewing, since my data is dynamically changing.

Anyone know of any way of doing this, or if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a JSON object to add attributes to clientside graphics on the fly.

API Reference - Graphic.attributes
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#attributes